# Яндекс.Метрика. Получить inout value

Tags: битрикс, яндекс-метрика

Есть проект на Битрикс, вывожу опросы через стандартный комплексный компонент vote, как получить значение (value) у input type="radio"?

Выводим компонентом, соответственно для всех вариантов ответа вывод строится через foreach.

Конечная цель - чтобы в Яндекс.Метрику сваливались результаты, выбранные пользователями (Да/Нет).

Может сталкивались?

Comment: где посмотреть можно? Вообще на отправку формы вешаем онклик или по сабмиту событие, считываем нужные поля и заполняем объект согласно схеме

Comment: `case 0://radio?>
     <label>
      <input <?=$value?> type="radio" name="vote_radio_<?=$arAnswer["QUESTION_ID"]?>" value="<?=$arAnswer["ID"]?>" <?=$arAnswer["~FIELD_PARAM"]?> />&nbsp;<?=$arAnswer["MESSAGE"]?>
      <span></span>
     </label>
     <br />
    <?break?>`

Comment: При ответе "Да" value=1, при "нет" соответственно value=2 (input value)